# I need help working with large files on GitHub to help my School

Tags: git, github, virtual-machine, virtualbox

hope you are all doing okay!

Well a little of context, I'm a of student CS and I'm coursing a programming class... We have had a lot of problems with my classmates and professor when it comes to managing the installations of different software needed for the class, because of COVID-19.

Last week the teacher and my classmates were very frustrated, so I decided to try and do something... I managed to create a Virtual Image of the environment needed for our class and the teacher want's to test it so he can be sure it works and I need to store it inside GitHub for accessibility. The idea is to present it to the director of the school and apply it to all of the other courses.

Problem is the .OVA weights over 1.5GB, is there any way to do this? (I'm from LATAM so it's hard for even the professor to access online resources because of the language barrier... he has no idea about how to make it work)

this is the error I'm getting and the push attempt:

```
`$ git push
Enumerating objects: 7, done.
Counting objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 1.19 GiB | 3.63 MiB/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: 5a70985822031aa2dd6d1dde62f31020
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File TecnicasCalidadDeSoftware.ova is 1240.53 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To github.com:Chrisvimu/TCY-Duoc2020.git
 ! [remot
```

e rejected] ChrisDev -> ChrisDev (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:Chrisvimu/TCY-Duoc2020.git'
`

Thanks for the answers, I asked with the aim to get insight into how to split an .OVA file without breaking it, but discovered my thought process was wrong. Again Thanks! :D

Comment: As the error message indicates, you cannot push files with size over 100 MB directly to GitHub. Try out https://git-lfs.github.com/ as mentioned and that should help

Comment: @MadhuBhat Thanks fort the reply I'll have LFS into consideration for the future, but I think my problem is better solve by using a storage like Google Drive :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub has a limit of 100 MB on files stored in a Git repository.  For many uses of large files, [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/) is a good option.

However, in your case, it seems like you're trying to store a virtual machine image in a Git repository and that's not a good idea, even with Git LFS.  Git repositories aren't designed as a binary asset store.  You shouldn't check in things like binary dependencies (DLLs or other shared libraries), data files, or virtual machine images, because those aren't a good fit for Git's use case, which is tracking the history of a project (source code or otherwise).

If you're creating a virtual machine image from a script, then you can check that script into the repository, tag the version, and then use GitHub releases to upload a built virtual machine image as a release asset for that tag, assuming that the image is under 2 GB.  You can compress it if desired to make it fit better.

If your goal is just to upload the file somewhere, then you'd be better off with a cloud storage service of some sort, such as Google Drive; a cloud bucket, such as one using Amazon S3; or an artifact server, such as Artifactory.

Comment: Thanks, there is a lot to of info on your response, I'll look into making a script on the future but for now I'll use Drive thanks for the insight it helped me a lot! :D

Answer (score 0):

GitHub has a file size limit of 100 megabytes (MB). Thus, you have to set up and install [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/) in order to push the file.

See this [guide](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/versioning-large-files) by GitHub as a reference to push your 1.5 GB file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've read the guide and now I got a grasp on what I should do :D!